# Encoding records as JSON objects with additional type field in Clojure

Tags: clojure, cheshire

Cheshire's custom encoders seem suitable for this problem and I wrote a little helper function:

```
(defn add-rec-encoder [Rec type-token]
  (add-encoder Rec
    (fn [rec jg] (.writeString jg
      (str (encode-map (assoc rec :type type-token) jg))))))

(defrecord A [a])

(add-rec-encoder A "A")

(encode (->A "abc"))
```

But it produces a strange trailing `""`.

`=> {"a":"abc","type":"A"} ""`

What is causing this? And is there another approach worth considering (I also need to be able to decode back to a record based on this type-token)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`(encode-map ... jg)` directly writes the encoded map to the JSON generator `jg`, then returns `nil`.

This means that, your call to `writeString` is actually:

```
(.writeString jg (str nil))
```

which, since `(str nil)` is `""`, will encode and append exactly that to the JSON generator. The correct encoder logic would be:

```
(defn add-rec-encoder [Rec type-token]
  (add-encoder Rec
    (fn [rec jg]
      (encode-map (assoc rec :type type-token) jg))))
```